# xinput - Ctrl+<Left> misbehaves if history-search-backward is mapped

Tags: bash, readline, xinput

I am using these lines in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

With these settings when I type <kbd>c</kbd> on the prompt and do a <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, bash only shows command starting with <kbd>c</kbd> from the history. <kbd>PageDown</kbd> does its inverse. I find this very much productive to me.

Without those lines in my inputrc file when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, The cursor use to go to one word left and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> does its opposite. But with those setting mentioned above when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> it prints `;5D` and `;5C` instead.

So how do I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> do the right stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `readline` commands for these movements are `forward-word` and `backward-word`. You can access them, respectively, using (the default emacs binds):
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>.

To get then working using the <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> keys, you need to add a couple of lines to your `~/.inputrc`.

First, confirm the correct escape sequences by getting the raw output from your terminal for those keypresses: enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> and make note of the sequence (something like `^[Oc` and `^[Od`). Then append these lines to your `.inputrc`:

```
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
```

All of the [readline commands](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_readline.htm) can be rebound in your `.inputrc`.

Answer (score 0):

note that those sequences may be different from one terminal to an other.
From your text, it seems that you use gnome-terminal.

```
# on gnome-terminal
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
```